# How to Recover Redis from Multiple RDB Files

Tags: redis, recovery

The multiple rdb files are from different redis servers. Now I want to combine the data files to a single redis server. By far I only find the answers to recover with a single dump.rdb file.

Comment: First thing I'd try is: start server with rdb, disable rdb aof preample with config set, enable aof with config set, and wait until the aof is written (some redis versions require a bgrewriteaof to trigger it). Do this for all rdb's, rename aof's intermediately. Afterwards, just cat together all aof files, and load it with an aof enabled redis conf.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting from Redis 6.0 `DEBUG RELOAD` `redis-cli` command got a new `NOSAVE` option that will ingest data from an RDB file (without overwriting it with memory dump and without the need to stop `redis-server`).

> `DEBUG RELOAD [MERGE] [NOFLUSH] [NOSAVE]`
>
> Save the RDB on disk and reload it back in memory. By default it will
> save the RDB file and load it back.
>
> With the `NOFLUSH` option **the current database is not removed before loading the new one**, but
> conficts in keys will kill the server with an exception.
>
> When `MERGE` is
> used, **conflicting keys will be loaded** (the key in the loaded RDB file
> will win).
>
> When `NOSAVE` is used, **the server will not save the current
> dataset in the RDB file before loading**.
>
> Use `DEBUG RELOAD NOSAVE` when
> you want just to load the RDB file you placed in the Redis working
> directory in order to replace the current dataset in memory.
>
> Use `DEBUG RELOAD NOSAVE NOFLUSH MERGE` when you want to add what is in the
> current RDB file placed in the Redis current directory, with the
> current memory content.
>
> Use `DEBUG RELOAD` when you want to verify Redis
> is able to persist the current dataset in the RDB file, flush the
> memory content, and load it back.",

The above is taken from `debug.c`, applied friendly format (see [debug.c source](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/7.0/src/debug.c#L445) for Redis 7.0).

So, use `DEBUG RELOAD NOSAVE NOFLUSH` if you want to ensure there are no duplicate keys in different RDBs. Use `DEBUG RELOAD NOSAVE NOFLUSH MERGE` if you know you have duplicates, load last the one you want to prevail.

Caution: versions of Redis earlier than 6.0 (without the NOSAVE option, see [debug.c source](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/5.0/src/debug.c#L317) for Redis 5.0) `DEBUG RELOAD` always began by overwriting the file with memory dump, an example of a silent fail, because `redis-cli` would accept any non-existing options after `DEBUG RELOAD`, not just "probable" ones such as `NOSAVE` but also completely contrived, such as `NOSAVING FAILS IN REDIS50`).